# Настройка левого края поля при печати

Tags: powershell, печать

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на PowerShell настроить левый край печати (отступ).
Вроде рабочий код, но не могу задать текст печати

```
$printDocument = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
$margins = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(10,10,10,10) # 50 twips = 0.5 inches
$printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = $margins
$printDocument.Print()
```

При помощи `Out-printer` текст печатается примерно в 3 сантиметрах от края листа, из-за этого очень много информации переносится на следующую строчку. Хотелось бы иметь возможность, изменения ширины(отступа) печати.

Answer (score 0):

Поиграйся с этим параметром

```
$printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
```

или первая десятка здесь

```
$margins = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(10,10,10,10)
```